# Was quick switch between mesh and armature removed in Blender 2.8?

Tags: armature, pose-mode

In Blender 2.79 I was able to quickly switch between mesh and armature in Pose Mode with right click on them. Same thing worked for switching between 2 different armatures. But I can't do that in Blender 2.8. I can't quickly select mesh and, for example, go to Edit Mode and do something. When I press the mesh while being in Pose Mode it doesn't switch to it. And when I have 2 armatures and one of them is in Pose Mode and another one is in Object Mode I still can't select Object Mode one. Is that a bug or a new feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for <kbd>Lock Object Modes</kbd>, which you can find in the 3D View Menu:

[image: lock object modes]

This was indeed added as a feature. For animators it is a bit cumbersome if they have to precisely click each bone during animation phase, that's why the modes are locked by default.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed!